Syscall interception using ptrace differs from strace output
I'm intercepting syscalls done by a child process using the ptrace functionality of the nix crate. In principle, my code is working in the sense that it is not crashing, syscalls are intercepted, and the target process operates as expected. But the syscalls reported by my code differ from those shown by strace for the same deterministic target process.
Here is a simplified version of my code, which, like strace, takes the target executable as a CLI argument and spawns it in a traced child process:
use std::{
    env,
    os::unix::process::CommandExt,
    process::{Command, ExitCode},
};

use nix::{
    libc,
    sys::{
        ptrace,
        wait::{waitpid, WaitStatus},
    },
    unistd::{fork, ForkResult, Pid},
};

fn run_in_child() {
    // Allow this process to be ptraced by the parent. When we replace the child
    // process with the target process down below, the traced process will get
    // paused by a SIGTRAP signal, for which we can wait in the parent process.
    // This allows us to make sure the parent process has finished setting up
    // its instrumentation before the target process really starts.
    ptrace::traceme().unwrap();

    // Skip the path of our own executable
    let mut args = env::args().skip(1);

    // Replace this child process with the target command
    let err = Command::new(args.next().unwrap()).args(args).exec();

    // The following is only executed if `exec` returned, which it only does in
    // case of an error.
    let cmd_str = env::args().skip(1).collect::<Vec<_>>().join(" ");
    println!("Could not execute '{cmd_str}': {err}");
    // Exit with the same error code
    let exit_code = err.raw_os_error().unwrap();
    unsafe { libc::_exit(exit_code) };
}

fn run_in_parent(child: Pid) {
    // The child uses `PTRACE_TRACEME` to allow itself to be traced. When the child
    // then calls `execve` it is stopped so that the parent (we) can finish our setup
    // before the child continues. Hence we wait here until the child has called
    // `execve`.
    waitpid(child, None).expect("Could not wait for child to be ready");
    println!("Child is ready");

    // By default, if the child is stopped at a syscall, we get notified of that as a
    // SIGTRAP. However, that can also happen for other reasons, so we tell ptrace to
    // distinguish syscalls by setting a special bit in the status. This allows us to
    // then match against WaitStatus::PtraceSyscall later.
    ptrace::setoptions(child, ptrace::Options::PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD)
        .expect("Could not set ptrace options");

    loop {
        ptrace::syscall(child, None).expect("Could not wait for syscall");
        match waitpid(child, None) {
            Ok(WaitStatus::Exited(_, exit_code)) => {
                println!("Child has exited with code {exit_code}");
                break;
            }
            Ok(WaitStatus::PtraceSyscall(..)) => {
                // Child is doing a syscall. To figure out the details about the call,
                // we need to inspect the registers
                let regs = ptrace::getregs(child).expect("Could not get user registers");

                // The number of the syscall is in the register `rax`. However, that
                // register is also used for the return value. Therefore, the original
                // value is stored separately.
                let syscall_num = regs.orig_rax;
                println!("Syscall #{syscall_num}");

                // We get notified both before the syscall happens and when it
                // returns. To avoid duplicates, we ignore the next event.
                ptrace::syscall(child, None).expect("Could not wait for syscall");
                match waitpid(child, None) {
                    Ok(WaitStatus::Exited(_, exit_code)) => {
                        println!("Child has exited with code {exit_code}");
                        break;
                    }
                    Ok(WaitStatus::PtraceSyscall(..)) => {
                        // Syscall returned as expected
                    }
                    x => {
                        println!("Something else: {x:?}")
                    }
                }
            }
            x => {
                println!("Something else: {x:?}")
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() -> ExitCode {
    if env::args().len() < 2 {
        println!("NOT ENOUGH ARGUMENTS");
        ExitCode::FAILURE
    } else {
        match unsafe { fork() } {
            Ok(ForkResult::Parent { child, .. }) => {
                run_in_parent(child);
                ExitCode::SUCCESS
            }
            Ok(ForkResult::Child) => {
                run_in_child();
                unsafe { libc::_exit(0) };
            }
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Fork failed");
                return ExitCode::FAILURE;
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm testing it against the following demo program, which I've compiled in a separate Cargo project using cargo build (and I'm then passing path/to/that/project/target/debug/syscall-test to my code and strace).
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

Here's a comparison of my code's output (on the left, annotated with the syscall names) and that of strace (on the right), with one syscall per line and gaps where one tool didn't report a syscall that the other did report.
brk (#12)                       brk(NULL)                               = 0x55dc6a72c000
arch_prctl (#158)               arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7fff972e04e0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
mmap (#9)
access (#21)                    access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat (#257)                   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
stat (#4)                       fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=133281, ...}) = 0
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
stat (#4)
openat (#257)
fstat (#5)
mmap (#9)                       mmap(NULL, 133281, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f924da2f000
close (#3)                      close(3)                                = 0
openat (#257)                   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read (#0)                       read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\3405\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat (#5)                      fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=104984, ...}) = 0
mmap (#9)                       mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f924da2d000
mmap (#9)                       mmap(NULL, 107592, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f924da12000
mmap (#9)                       mmap(0x7f924da15000, 73728, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f924da15000
mmap (#9)                       mmap(0x7f924da27000, 16384, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x7f924da27000
                                mmap(0x7f924da2b000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18000) = 0x7f924da2b000
close (#3)                      close(3)                                = 0
openat (#257)                   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat (#257)
openat (#257)
openat (#257)
openat (#257)
read (#0)                       read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220q\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64 (#17)                   pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\f\4K\246\21\256\356\256\273\203t\346`\6\0374"..., 68, 824) = 68
fstat (#5)                      fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=157224, ...}) = 0
pread64 (#17)                   pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\f\4K\246\21\256\356\256\273\203t\346`\6\0374"..., 68, 824) = 68
mmap (#9)                       mmap(NULL, 140408, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f924d9ef000
mmap (#9)                       mmap(0x7f924d9f5000, 69632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f924d9f5000
mmap (#9)                       mmap(0x7f924da06000, 24576, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7f924da06000
mmap (#9)                       mmap(0x7f924da0c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c000) = 0x7f924da0c000
mmap (#9)                       mmap(0x7f924da0e000, 13432, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f924da0e000
close (#3)                      close(3)                                = 0
openat (#257)                   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat (#257)
openat (#257)
openat (#257)
openat (#257)
read (#0)                       read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \22\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat (#5)                      fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18848, ...}) = 0
mmap (#9)                       mmap(NULL, 20752, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f924d9e9000
mmap (#9)                       mmap(0x7f924d9ea000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7f924d9ea000
mmap (#9)                       mmap(0x7f924d9ec000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f924d9ec000
mmap (#9)                       mmap(0x7f924d9ed000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f924d9ed000
close (#3)                      close(3)                                = 0
openat (#257)                   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat (#257)
openat (#257)
openat (#257)
openat (#257)
read (#0)                       read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300A\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64 (#17)                   pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64 (#17)                   pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64 (#17)                   pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\356\276]_K`\213\212S\354Dkc\230\33\272"..., 68, 880) = 68
fstat (#5)                      fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2029592, ...}) = 0
pread64 (#17)                   pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64 (#17)                   pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64 (#17)                   pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\356\276]_K`\213\212S\354Dkc\230\33\272"..., 68, 880) = 68
mmap (#9)                       mmap(NULL, 2037344, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f924d7f7000
mmap (#9)                       mmap(0x7f924d819000, 1540096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x22000) = 0x7f924d819000
mmap (#9)                       mmap(0x7f924d991000, 319488, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19a000) = 0x7f924d991000
mmap (#9)                       mmap(0x7f924d9df000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f924d9df000
mmap (#9)                       mmap(0x7f924d9e5000, 13920, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f924d9e5000
close (#3)                      close(3)                                = 0
mmap (#9)                       mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f924d7f5000
arch_prctl (#158)               arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f924d7f5bc0) = 0
mprotect (#10)                  mprotect(0x7f924d9df000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect (#10)                  mprotect(0x7f924d9ed000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect (#10)                  mprotect(0x7f924da0c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect (#10)                  mprotect(0x7f924da2b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect (#10)                  mprotect(0x55dc689a7000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect (#10)                  mprotect(0x7f924da7d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap (#11)                    munmap(0x7f924da2f000, 133281)          = 0
set_tid_address (#218)          set_tid_address(0x7f924d7f5e90)         = 110877
set_robust_list (#273)          set_robust_list(0x7f924d7f5ea0, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction (#13)              rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7f924d9f5bf0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f924da03420}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction (#13)              rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7f924d9f5c90, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f924da03420}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask (#14)            rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
prlimit64 (#302)                prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
poll (#7)                       poll([{fd=0, events=0}, {fd=1, events=0}, {fd=2, events=0}], 3, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigaction (#13)              rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f924d83a090}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction (#13)              rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction (#13)              rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {sa_handler=0x55dc68974960, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_ONSTACK|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f924da03420}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction (#13)              rt_sigaction(SIGBUS, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction (#13)              rt_sigaction(SIGBUS, {sa_handler=0x55dc68974960, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_ONSTACK|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f924da03420}, NULL, 8) = 0
sigaltstack (#131)              sigaltstack(NULL, {ss_sp=NULL, ss_flags=SS_DISABLE, ss_size=0}) = 0
mmap (#9)                       mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f924da4d000
mprotect (#10)                  mprotect(0x7f924da4d000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
sigaltstack (#131)              sigaltstack({ss_sp=0x7f924da4e000, ss_flags=0, ss_size=8192}, NULL) = 0
brk (#12)                       brk(NULL)                               = 0x55dc6a72c000
brk (#12)                       brk(0x55dc6a74d000)                     = 0x55dc6a74d000
openat (#257)                   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
prlimit64 (#302)                prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
fstat (#5)                      fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read (#0)                       read(3, "55dc6894d000-55dc68953000 r--p 0"..., 1024) = 1024
read (#0)                       read(3, "0-7f924d9df000 r--p 0019a000 fd:"..., 1024) = 1024
read (#0)                       read(3, "_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so"..., 1024) = 1024
read (#0)                       read(3, "da2d000 rw-p 00019000 fd:01 4613"..., 1024) = 1024
close (#3)                      close(3)                                = 0
sched_getaffinity (#204)        sched_getaffinity(110877, 32, [0, 1, 2, 3]) = 8
write (#1)                      write(1, "Hello, world!\n", 14Hello, world!) = 14
sigaltstack (#131)              sigaltstack({ss_sp=NULL, ss_flags=SS_DISABLE, ss_size=8192}, NULL) = 0
munmap (#11)                    munmap(0x7f924da4d000, 12288)           = 0
exit_group (#231)               exit_group(0)                           = ?

As you can see, my code reports more syscalls than strace does, but in a one case it's also the other way round. Where does this difference come from?
I'm running the standard strace from Ubuntu 20.04 (strace 5.5), Rust 1.72.1, and the nix crate in version 0.28.0. The output of each tool is consistent across multiple runs (aside from the memory addresses in that of strace).

You're not tracing clone (PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE) to attach and trace new threads. Are you sure the child process is single-threaded?

@Useless: Well, my target code only prints Hello, world!, so it should be single-threaded. And even if it was multi-threaded, wouldn't my tracing code then report fewer syscalls than strace?

Oh yeah, you're right. I suppose both versions are running with exactly the same $PATH and other environment variables? The extra openat calls might be explained if one version was trying more places to find stuff ...

They're running from the same shell session, one right after the other.

I found the issue: I was running my tracing code (not the target code) via cargo run.
My assumption was that this is equivalent to checking whether anything needs to be rebuilt and then executing the binary as the shell would, but it seems that something in the environment is different when the code is run via cargo, and this difference is causing additional syscalls during the setup of the child process (this comment by @Useless got me on the right track).
If I execute the compiled tracing code directly (i.e. via the binary in target/) then the output matches those of strace.
